# Azure CDN with URL rewrite for SAS and CDN auth token

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have set those two rules feature in the order of

1. CDN Token auth enabled
2. URL rewrite to append SAS token.

At first, I did the 2nd step and tested a file successfully (only CDN url eg. https://cdn.azureedge.net/blobcontainer/blobname.jpg)

Then, on adding CDN token auth, the CDN url (CDN+CDN auth token eg. https://cdn.azureedge.net/blobcontainer/blobname.jpg?cdnauthtoken) hits only works for files I already accessed in previous step, using the SAS rewrite rule, but not for any other files in the same storage container.

Tried this too:
[Split the CDN url and cdn token from parent url, and append SAS to CDN url](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a35dcb3c-719e-4131-8355-3b4b9c13b85b/azure-cdn-with-sas-token-and-authentication-token?forum=azurecdn)

Any thoughts?